# How to define basePath in Swagger 3.0 inside Wildfly

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, wildfly-11

I integrated Swagger-ui in my wildfly application.

The project is configured through maven with the following (relevant) dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also extracted the swagger-ui.html page from the webjar and customized the javascript to connect to my server as follow (see the url):

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Begin Swagger UI call region
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "doc/openapi.json",
    dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
  // End Swagger UI call region

  window.ui = ui
}
```

The swagger-ui is working well, it displays the list of my endpoints. But when I try to connect to my endpoints, it fails because the url used to connect does not contain the context path of my application (*myApp* here), it tries to connect with:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/aop/hello/version" -H "accept: */*"
```

But it should be:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/myApp/aop/hello/version" -H "accept: */*"
```

I found that the missing part is named the basePath but I did not find any solution to add it in my Wildfly application.

**Update:**
Following the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/), it seems that the basePath comes from Swagger, the OpenApi uses a *server*.
Then I tried:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application 
{
    public ApplicationConfig(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        // Swagger Configuration
        super();
        OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI()
                .servers(Collections.singletonList(new Server().url("http://localhost:8080/my_app")));
        Info info = new Info()
                .title("Swagger");

        oas.info(info);
        SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
                .openAPI(oas)
                .prettyPrint(true);

        try {
            new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder<>()
                    .servletConfig(servletConfig)
                    .application(this)
                    .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
                    .buildContext(true);
        } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
            throw new ConfigurationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is still not taken into account.

Any lead?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got it working, but not with the Java configuration which is not taken into account (seen in debug) but using a configuration file *openapi.yaml* in the classpath of the application.

The file looks like:

```
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
openAPI:
  servers:
    - url: /my_app
  info:
    version: '1.0'
    title: Swagger application
```

With the server url now correctly handled.

But I am still curious to know what should be the right solution for a Java configuration.

Comment: `.servers(Collections.singletonList(new Server().url("/my_app")))` works for java.

Answer (score 1):

Provided at Global Level it is working fine in java

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = @Server(url="/my_app"))
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and for some reason your solution with openapi.yaml did not work for me either.

Then I found that you can use the Server annotation with your service/resource class:

```
@Path("/myservice")
@Server(url="/my_app")
public interface MyService {
...
}
```